# Display different HTML elements based on array's index

Tags: php, python, html, arrays, web-scraping

I am using Python to scrape through a webpage and then download its table data, `<td>` elements, and store them in file as JSON. Afterwards, I use PHP to process that data and display it in a table:

```
<?php
    $file_content = file_get_contents("./file.txt");
    $decoded_json = json_decode($file_content); // $decoded_json becomes an array with 72 elements (each of the elements is a string)
?>
```

Each row of the table where I got data from has 24 columns. Basically I have 3 rows now (72 elements in an array). I need to create 3`<tr>` and 24 `<td>` for each row - *dynamically* because each time number of rows I scrape may change. Also, I need to add `<input type="checkbox">` next to 18th, 21st, and 24th column in my table. Here is what I have so far (it looks at least somewhat close to what I want to achieve):

```
<table>
    <?php
        $i = 0;
        while ($i <= count($decoded_json)) {
            if ($i % 24 === 0) {
                echo "<tr><td>$decoded_json[$i]</td></tr>";
                $i++;
            } else {
                if ($i % 18 === 0 || $i % 21 === 0 || $i % 24 === 0) {
                    echo "<td>$decoded_json[$i]</td>";
                    echo '<td><input type="checkbox"></td>'; // It does not echo checkboxes correctly because of $i. 
                    $i++;
                } else {
                    echo "<td>$decoded_json[$i]</td>";
                    $i++;
                }  
            }
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

Questions:

- Is this a feasible approach at all?

If yes:

1. How can I make sure only 1 row is created for each 24 elements in an array (even if my array consists of thousands of elements)? Right now 1 row is created for each 23 elements, and 1st element of 24 is always left out.
2. How can I add a checkbox next to 18th, 21st, and 24th column of each row? Because I increment `$i` on every iteration, number is growing, but I guess I have to keep it between 1-24 for every row.

If no:

1. Which approach would you recommend to use? I prefer PHP.

P.S. I hope I was clear. If not, please ask for clarification. My title may look vague but I did not know how to specify my question in 1 sentence.

**Edit (replying to @ggorlen comment):**
Here is the file content:

```
["first", "768.51", "4,680", "0", "0%", "0", "0", "0%", "0", "0", "0%", "0", "0.00", "0.00%", "2", "0", "0%", "0", "0.00", "0.00%", "1", "768.51", "100.00%", "4,677", "second", "547.80", "27,392", "0", "0%", "0", "0", "0%", "0", "0", "0%", "0", "44.30", "8.09%", "138", "503.50", "91.91%", "27,254", "0", "0%", "0", "0", "0%", "0", "third", "509.41", "59,777", "0", "0%", "0", "0", "0%", "0", "0", "0%", "0", "0.00", "0.00%", "1", "412.94", "81.06%", "9,972", "22.15", "4.35%", "6,118", "74.32", "14.59%", "43,686"]
```

Here is what I want to get (sort of; I just need checkboxes next to the 18th, 21st, and 24th columns of each row):

```html
<html><head><title>The Website Title</title></head>
<body>

<table border="1">

<td>first</td><td align="right">768.51</td> <td align="right">4,680</td><td align="right">0</td> <td align="right">0%</td> <td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0</td> <td align="right">0%</td> <td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0</td> <td align="right">0%</td> <td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0.00</td> <td align="right">0.00%</td> <td align="right"></td><td align="right">0</td> <td align="right">0%</td> <td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0.00</td> <td align="right">0.00%</td> <td align="right"><a >1</a></td><td align="right">768.51</td> <td align="right">100.00%</td> <td align="right"><a >4,677</a></td></tr>

<tr>
<td>second</td><td align="right">547.80</td> <td align="right">27,392</td><td align="right">0</td> <td align="right">0%</td> <td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0</td> <td align="right">0%</td> <td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0</td> <td align="right">0%</td> <td align="right">0</td><td align="right">44.30</td> <td align="right">8.09%</td> <td align="right"><a >138</a></td><td align="right">503.50</td> <td align="right">91.91%</td> <td align="right"><a >27,254</a></td><td align="right">0</td> <td align="right">0%</td> <td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0</td> <td align="right">0%</td> <td align="right">0</td></tr>

<tr>
<td>third</td><td align="right">509.41</td> <td align="right">59,777</td><td align="right">0</td> <td align="right">0%</td> <td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0</td> <td align="right">0%</td> <td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0</td> <td align="right">0%</td> <td align="right">0</td><td align="right">0.00</td> <td align="right">0.00%</td> <td align="right"><a>1</a></td><td align="right">412.94</td> <td align="right">81.06%</td> <td align="right"><a >9,972</a></td><td align="right">22.15</td> <td align="right">4.35%</td> <td align="right"><a>6,118</a></td><td align="right">74.32</td> <td align="right">14.59%</td> <td align="right">43,686<</td></tr>

</table>


</body></html>
```

Comment: It seems like the Python/web scraping part is irrelevant. I'd recommend posting a [complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including your input file content and the expected DOM you'd like to render from that so answerers can show a working code example. Otherwise, leaving it up to guesswork and assumptions means you're less likely to wind up with an answer that solves your problem. Also, your approach looks generally feasible and good except your closing `</tr>` tag will be prematurely inserted.

Comment: @ggorlen I have added file content and something close to what I want to get out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is close. The idea is to formulate the 1d array in terms of rows and columns somehow. My approach was to increment the outer row loop by the number of desired columns (24).

For each row, I `echo` the opening `<tr>` tag, then iterate over all the columns in an inner loop and place cells and checkboxes as appropriate. Each cell's index is `$row + $col` (`$col + $row < count($decoded_json)` is a safety check). Finally, I close the row's `</tr>` and move on to the next row, which begins 24 indices further in the array.

```
$columns = 24;
$checkboxes = array_flip([17, 20, 23]);

for ($row = 0; $row < count($decoded_json); $row += $columns) {
    echo '<tr>';

    for ($col = 0; $col < $columns && $col + $row < count($decoded_json); $col++) {
        echo '<td>' . $decoded_json[$row+$col] . '</td>';
        
        if (array_key_exists($col, $checkboxes)) {
            echo '<td><input type="checkbox"></td>';
        }
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Here's the tidied HTML output:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-family: monospace;
}

tr,
td {
  padding: 0.6em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>first</td>
    <td>768.51</td>
    <td>4,680</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00%</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00%</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>768.51</td>
    <td>100.00%</td>
    <td>4,677</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>second</td>
    <td>547.80</td>
    <td>27,392</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>44.30</td>
    <td>8.09%</td>
    <td>138</td>
    <td>503.50</td>
    <td>91.91%</td>
    <td>27,254</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>third</td>
    <td>509.41</td>
    <td>59,777</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0%</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0.00</td>
    <td>0.00%</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>412.94</td>
    <td>81.06%</td>
    <td>9,972</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>22.15</td>
    <td>4.35%</td>
    <td>6,118</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>74.32</td>
    <td>14.59%</td>
    <td>43,686</td>
    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```